# Arduino I2S sine wave

Tags: arduino, trigonometry

I'm working on a project where I want to generate (simple) sound by combining different sine waves. I'm using an arduino mkrZero, as it has I2S interface built in and it seems to have enough processing power for what I want.

I have wired my system exactly like in the tutorial for arduino I2S simpleTone:[image]

And the [tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/I2SSimpleTone) code works just fine, and I get a simple square wave tone from the speaker.

Now I have modified the code to generate sine wave, there is a lookup table for the sin function to make it fast enough:

```
#include <I2S.h>

uint16_t isin16[] = {
 0, 1144, 2287, 3430, 4571, 5712, 6850, 7987, 9121, 10252, 11380,
 12505, 13625, 14742, 15854, 16962, 18064, 19161, 20251, 21336, 22414,
 23486, 24550, 25607, 26655, 27696, 28729, 29752, 30767, 31772, 32768,

 33753, 34728, 35693, 36647, 37589, 38521, 39440, 40347, 41243, 42125,
 42995, 43851, 44695, 45524, 46340, 47142, 47929, 48702, 49460, 50203,
 50930, 51642, 52339, 53019, 53683, 54331, 54962, 55577, 56174, 56755,

 57318, 57864, 58392, 58902, 59395, 59869, 60325, 60763, 61182, 61583,
 61965, 62327, 62671, 62996, 63302, 63588, 63855, 64103, 64331, 64539,
 64728, 64897, 65047, 65176, 65286, 65375, 65445, 65495, 65525, 65535,
 }; //0-90


const int sincount = 2;
int freqs[] = {50*360,51*360};
float amps[] ={0.1,0.1}; 

const int sampleRate = 8000; // sample rate in Hz

short sample = 0;
double t = 0;
double dt = 1.0/(1.0*sampleRate);

short LR[] = {0,0};

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(115200);
  // start I2S at the sample rate with 16-bits per sample
  if (!I2S.begin(I2S_PHILIPS_MODE, sampleRate, 16)) {
    while (1); // do nothing
  }
}

void loop() {
    sample = 0;
    for(int n= 0;n<sincount;n++)
    {
      sample += fSin(freqs[n]*t)*amps[n];
    }
    t += dt;
    LR[0] = sample;
    LR[1] = sample;

   I2S.write(LR[0]);//left channel
   I2S.write(LR[1]);//right channel
}


float fSin(long x)
{
 boolean pos = true;  // positive - keeps an eye on the sign.
 if (x < 0)
 {
   x = -x;
   pos = false;  
 }  
 if (x >= 360) x %= 360;  
 if (x > 180)
 {
   x -= 180;
   pos = !pos;
 }
 if (x > 90) x = 180 - x;
 if (pos) return isin16[x]; // = /65535.0
 return isin16[x];
}
```

This also works fine.

**BUT!**

If I change the code a bit and I write

```
I2S.write(LR,2);
```

instead of

```
I2S.write(LR[0]);//left channel
I2S.write(LR[1]);//right channel
```

Everything just breaks, the sound from the speaker sounds like a [horrible scream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Eos0wg7QJU)

From the I2S library reference:

> **Description**
>
> Writes binary data to the I2S interface. This data is sent as a sample
>   or series of samples.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `I2S.write(val)` // blocking
>
> `I2S.write(buf, len)` // not blocking
>
> **Parameters**
>
> val: a value to send as a single sample
>
> buf: an array to send as a series of samples
>
> len: the length of the buffer
>
> **Returns**
>
> byte write() will return the number of bytes written, though reading
>   that number is optional.

I'd like to use the latter version of the write function, because it is not blocking and I can generate new samples while the previous ones are playing.

Any ideas on how to make the buffered version work correctly as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you declare `LR` as an `array of 2 short`, a `short` in **Arduino** has size `2 bytes`.

When you write this:

```cpp
I2S.write(LR[0]); //left channel
I2S.write(LR[1]); //right channel
```

given

```cpp
size_t I2SClass::write(uint8_t data)
{
    return write((int32_t)data);
}

size_t I2SClass::write(int sample)
{
    return write((int32_t)sample);
}
```

your `short` values should be automatically **promoted** to fit into the `int` type. Now, I am a bit *unsure* on the size of `int` you are dealing with, because the only **I2S.h** library I found is for the **SAMD** board [on which an `int` has `4 bytes` size](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Int), but normally on **Arduino** the an `int` has size of `2 bytes`. In either case, the value should be taken as is, without problems.

When you write this:

```cpp
I2S.write(LR,2);
```

given

```cpp
size_t I2SClass::write(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size)
{
    return write((const void*)buffer, size);
}

size_t I2SClass::write(const void *buffer, size_t size)
{
    ...
    written = _doubleBuffer.write(buffer, size);
    ...
}
```

your `array of 2 short` should be cast to `const void *`.

From this code in [I2SDoubleBuffer](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-samd/blob/master/libraries/I2S/src/utility/I2SDoubleBuffer.cpp):

```cpp
size_t I2SDoubleBuffer::write(const void *buffer, size_t size) {
  size_t space = availableForWrite();

  if (size > space) {
    size = space;
  }

  if (size == 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  memcpy(&_buffer[_index][_length[_index]], buffer, size);

  _length[_index] += size;

  return size;
}
```

it looks like `_doubleBuffer` is not aware of the **declared** size of a **sample** (you declared it to be of `16 bits`), it merely copies `size` bytes from the input to the internal buffer.

Therefore, I **guess** that what really happens is that when you ask for `2 shorts` to be buffered only `2 bytes` are actually copied.

---

**Example:**

Assume that your `LR` contains the following values

```cpp
short LR[2] = { 0x89AB, 0xCDEF };
```

then this is what **I imagine** it happens

```cpp
I2S.write(LR[0]); // actual left sample is 0x89AB
I2S.write(LR[1]); // actual right sample is 0xCDEF

I2S.write(LR, 2); // actual left sample is 0x89AB
                  // 0xCDEF is not copied
/* next loop iteration */
I2S.write(LR, 2); // actual right sample is 0x89AB 
                  // 0xCDEF is not copied
```

---

**Proposed Solution:**

Try to ask for `4 bytes` to be copied:

```
I2S.write(LR, 4); // actual left sample is 0x89AB 
                  // actual right sample is 0xCDEF
```