# Arduino wave generator

Tags: arduino, waveform, trigonometry

I need to create an Arduino Wave Generator, but I realy can't get it to work properly.

The generator must output Sine, Square, Triangle and Sawtooth waves, I got the square one working, I tried a lot of things, but can't get the others to work properly.

Here's my circuit:

[image]

And here's the code that I'm using

```
int led1 = 3;
int led2 = 4;
int led3 = 5;
int led4 = 6;
int display = 13;

int inBtn = 8;
int btnSt = 0;
int btnLastSt = 0;

int cont = 0;

void setup() {

  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(display, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(inBtn, INPUT);

}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
  switch(cont){
      case 0:
            digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);    
            digitalWrite(display, HIGH);
            delay(250);
            digitalWrite(display, LOW);
            delay(250);
            break;
      case 1:
            digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
            break;
      case 2:
            digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
            break;
      case 3:
            digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
            break;
  }  
  if (digitalRead(inBtn) == LOW) {
    cont++;
    delay(150);
  }
  if (cont == 4) cont = 0;

  if (btnLastSt != cont){
    btnLastSt = cont;
  }

}
```

The others waves would go inside the other 'cases'.
I'm sorry about the lack of info and research, but at this point I'm quite desperate (it's an assignment).

If someone could help me a bit on this, would be great.

**UPDATE**

Here's my final circuit and code, after Gerhard's help.
[image]

```
int led1 = 3;
int led2 = 4;
int led3 = 5;
int led4 = 6;
int display = 11;

int inBtn = 8;
int btnSt = 0;
int btnLastSt = 0;

int cont = 0;

void setup() {

  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(display, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(inBtn, INPUT);

}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
  switch(cont){
      case 0:
            //Square
            digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);    
            digitalWrite(display, HIGH);
            delay(200);
            digitalWrite(display, LOW);
            delay(200);
            break;
      case 1:
            //Sawtooth
            digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
            for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++){
                analogWrite(display, i);
                delay(1);   
            }
            analogWrite(display, 0);
            delay(1);
            break;
    case 2:
            //Triangular
            digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
            for (int i = 0; i < 254; i++){
                analogWrite(display, i);
                delay(1);
            }
            for (int i2 = 254; i2 > 0; i2--){
                analogWrite(display, i2);
                delay(1); 
            }

           break;
      case 3:
            //Sine
            digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
            analogWrite(display, 10); delay(10);
            analogWrite(display, 19); delay(10);
            analogWrite(display, 45); delay(10);
            analogWrite(display, 84); delay(10);
            analogWrite(display, 130); delay(10);
            analogWrite(display, 176); delay(10);
            analogWrite(display, 215); delay(10);
            analogWrite(display, 241); delay(10);
            analogWrite(display, 250); delay(10);
            analogWrite(display, 241); delay(10);
            analogWrite(display, 215); delay(10);
            analogWrite(display, 176); delay(10);
            analogWrite(display, 130); delay(10);
            analogWrite(display, 84); delay(10);
            analogWrite(display, 45); delay(10);
            analogWrite(display, 19); delay(10);
            break;
  }  
  if (digitalRead(inBtn) == LOW) {
    cont++;
    delay(100);
  }
  if (cont == 4) cont = 0;

  if (btnLastSt != cont){
    btnLastSt = cont;
  }

}
```

It's not perfect, but it's good enough haha.

Comment: some info on DAC here https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/using-the-arduinos-analog-io/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hardware setup is insufficient for what you want to achieve.

You need an analog output but you are using a digital output. You have to add a DAC (Digital to Analog Converter) ([MAX98357A example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097910/arduino-i2s-sine-wave)) or use the PWM (Pulse Width Modulation) outputs (pins 3,5,6,9-11). Both of these would also require an additional LPF (low pass filter) on the output.

For PWM you setup the output `pinMode(pin, OUTPUT)` and can then use `analogWrite(pin, value)` with values on a scale of 0 - 255.

Comment: Thanks! 
I managed to get it to work properly. I'll update the question later, just in case someone needs it in the future.